# Display window form popup for a short span and then close it automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have created one windows form as pop up screen. I need to display that form as pop up in my windows application for few time only.

For the time being it will be shown and after some time it will be close automatically.

I need to display that form in MDI parent file as lower right corner.

How can I do that ?

Comment: show us your code so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you can do..It works like a `Splash Screen`

```
private void popup()
    {

        Thread th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        });
        th.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);   //you can update this time as your requirement
        th.Abort();
    }

    private void Open()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.ShowDialog();   // frm.Show(); if MDI Parent form
    }
```

Comment: I need to display that form when I start my application. If I use this code than my application will be delay for time which I mentioned in Thread.Sleep(). I need to display that pop up as notification or it will not affect other activities which will normally happens in windows application

Comment: No..It will wait for 3 minutes to close that form so it is not a delay for opening but it's a delay for closing..This is just works as a `slpash screen`...just call `popup()` function from the `Main()` form

Comment: but i dont want to display that pop up for 3 minutes only... I need to display that form as background process.

Comment: You can use `background worker` for that..Refer this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435752/c-sharp-how-can-i-open-a-second-winform-asynchronously-but-still-behave-as-a-c) @LajjaThaker

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to trigger an that the popup window processes to close itself.

There are other timer classes in the .NET Framework.  This timer takes care to call the UI event handler on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is a splash screen. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C) a nice article about it.