# Providing data to dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, dialog

I have `static class ControlCenter`, which in time-intervals communicates with external system.
For every single question&answer to external system my `ControlCenter` raises `event` which provides status information UI layer. Even if communication fails, `event` with error mesage is raised.

Now problem:
If there are some communication errors i want show form or dialog box in **dialog mode** so user can interact only with this showed UI item.

Even if there is an error, communication between ControlCenter and UI layer continues and I want provide to showed dialog actual data for exampl *"Trying to reconnect....3rd try from 20 do you want kill service?"*

I want be able hide this dialog form from itself by user click or programatically from its parent form (top ui layer).

I was trying create my own Form consuming event with data from its parent form and showing `MyForm.ShowDialog()`; but after showdialog() UIlayer waits on user action with dialog.

Do you know pls some walkthrough for this context? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would help if you could post your code showing the problem.

Comment: @GrantWinney: I was expecting this :) I am looking for another solution, I dont believe thats right walkthrough. I described it to prove that I tried some progress myself before asking here. 
What I want is: Show standard dialog box which real-time consumes data from its parent. "Place of kill" of this dialog form is irelevant because if i will able to provide "some" data to dialog a can tell him that he should close self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435752/open-a-second-winform-asynchronously-but-still-behave-as-a-child-to-the-parent-f) question is very similar to yours and has a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435775/2974754) with a sample. It boils down to using `BackgroundWorker` class for retrieving needed information.

Comment: thanks, it helped me solve problem. I did not think to look under that name.