# form.show() behaves like form.showDialog()

Tags: c#, showdialog

I have a very strange problems.
I'm running a process which takes some time, during it I want to show a modaless window.
This is my code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Process[] FileProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeFile.exe");

    if (FileProcess.Length == 1)
        wait_debug.ShowDialog();
        wait_debug.TopMost = true;
});

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SomeFile.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = work_directory;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
```

Maybe I did mixed it up, but is it wrong to put the 'wait_debug.showdialog' inside a thread?

The whole point I put it there in the first place was to make it modaless, but if I'll use Show(), it get stuck.

I'm getting all kind of weird stuff... can someone help to point me to the right direction?

**I want the 'wait_debug' window to be on top AND be modaless, while the process is running.**

No matter what I try, I can't get it to work. Sometimes the wait_debug form is stuck, even though it is modaless (there's a cancel button in this form, and some graphics - they are all stuck, even though the beneath form is responsive, and after a few seconds - everything crashes).

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, [it is wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  Don't display UI on a worker thread.  Use worker threads to do work that "takes some time".

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what do you propse? If I use ShowDialog() it doesn't get stuck, and the form beneath is responsive (even though it should be modal, this is weird) but I can't keep it topmost, whatever I try...

Comment: I believe it's two years I was looking for pretty much same topic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270663/providing-data-to-dialog
Hope it will help.

Comment: By the way it will serve you well to always use `{}` for `if` statements; right now `wait_debug.TopMost = true;` will always be executed, which is probably not what you intended judging by the indentation.

Comment: Yes, of course. You're right. typo.