# Show modal loading window in Winforms for long-running process

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I would like to show a wait gif, while verifying a file and this is what I have tried so far.
There is a form - Form1, where user clicks a button to verify a file, and there is another form - Wait, with just a picturebox showing a gif image.

```
button_click()
{
  Wait wait = new Wait();
  wait.ShowDialog();
  VerifyFile();
  wait.Close();
}
```

The Wait form does show up, but it doesn't close. Also, the verification is also not done. It continues only when I manually close the Wait form.
How to auto close the wait form, once `VerifyFile()` is complete.

Comment: You need to look into creating callbacks, delegates, and asynchronous processes. The process you're waiting for will need to make a callback to the waiting form when it's done so that your wait form can then close. If you want to have a progress bar then you'll need more callbacks during your long running process. This is gonna be your best bet. It's not something I've done yet but I've seen it done in my experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a second winform asynchronously but still behave as a child to the parent form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435752/open-a-second-winform-asynchronously-but-still-behave-as-a-child-to-the-parent-f)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that Form.ShowDialog() method is synchronous and it waits for the result from the "Form" dialog. This means that the code execution is hold up untill the "wait" dialog will be closed.

Consider moving the VerifyFile() method into Wait dialog:

```
class Wait: Form
{
    public Wait() : base() 
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => VerifyFile());
    }
}
```

You can close this dialog when after VerifyFile execute's over.

Comment: Its not a good design to move the task to a form which is just meant to show that something is in progress.

Comment: Whole OOP design is one big mistake but still people use it... I dont know why people from here cares about "design patterns" and such. If you want to then be creative, post tons of code lines just to show example that is "well designed"..